# Couldn't run ChromeDriver using selenium

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```java
package testPackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./Driver/chromedriver.exe");
        // Create a new instance of the ChromeDriver
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        
    }

}
```

Error Image :
[image]

I've added `selenium-java-4.9.0.jar` in my classpath.
But I still get errors as :-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    ChromeDriver cannot be resolved to a type
    ChromeDriver cannot be resolved to a type

    at TestProject/testPackage.TestClass.main(TestClass.java:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be your selenium jar file is either not configure properly or it's not present,
try this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8XZT1oOg7as
or try this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OHtRHXPJn7U

I think this might help, I faced the same issue and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

check whether you had added correct selenium jar files or not